# Indexing regular expressions (preferable in Lucene)

Tags: java, regex, search, lucene, indexing

Does anyone know of a way of **indexing regular expressions**, so that I can run non-regex queries, matching against documents with a regex field in them? Preferably with Lucene or another in-process Java library.

### Background

I work on a project where we want to classify large numbers of user-transactions. We have tools to do this now, but we need to optimize.

Currently I am exploring lucene to replace an inmemory sorted tree built of implementation using HashMaps, ConcurrentSkipListSets in a parent-child relationship.

```
a  -> category cat1
   1  -> category cat2 

b  -> category cat4 
   \w*  
      6 -> category cat5
```

So a string *'a 1'* and *'a 1 z x y'* would match  *'cat2'*, *'a'* would match  *'cat1'* and *'b x y 6'* would match *'cat5'*. All rules have an implicit *'.*'* at the end, and if a match is possible without regex matching it is preferred. These rules are built from property lists:

```
a        = cat1
a 1      = cat2
b        = cat4
b \w* 6  = cat5
```

We are pushing 50k rules now (and increasing) and while this process is very fast at lookups, it uses too much RAM, takes a bit time to build, and is not as flexible as we need.

I have experimented with Lucene for indexing these rules, but I am having trouble since the regex matches a lot of common words (in our domain), and it is not easy to build stopwords for these, as they also change quite often.

So to reiterate - I need a way to search for documents where the regular expression is indexed, and the query does not know about the regular expression at all.

Anyone?

-- Olve

Comment: The letters and numbers in my example does of course not represent real world values.

Comment: why don't you just escape special characters in your query? http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping Special Characters

Comment: When I enter a query for say *'b x y 6'* as above, I do not know at query-time that *'x y'* will be matched against the regex part of the rule *'b \w* 6'. I want the match to be as similar to the query-string as possible, but with the regex in the index (and the implicit *'.\*'* at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene can't help you with your problem, if you have n regular expressions and want to find one that matches your input, there is not better way to do this than running every regular expression against your input. Actually there is one, which is to merge all your regular expressions in a finite state machine but this is what you are currently doing.

However, I am surprised that your process uses too much RAM with only 50k rules. How much RAM do you have? If you agree to share your implementations details, I am sure that that there is room for improvement.

Regarding the build time, how does your application work? Maybe it would be possible to store a compiled version of your data structure on disk to improve the startup time and then only modify it with incremental updates.

Comment: I have already stared to come to the same conclusion. I started looking into creating my own KeywordAnalyzer/Tokenizer version but I am not sure if it is possible. I have some Lucene experience, but not with the internals. We will optimize the structure we have now, and support patching the structure with updates, and using arrays instead of SortedSets/Maps. I guess this might increase the build-time, but reduce the memory footprint. One challenge though is to properly tokenize regular expressions - now we support only \w* and \d*

Comment: We are a bit constrained on RAM - and we rebuild the entire structure on changes, so we consume double of the size during rebuilds. I guess the structure itself uses about 40-50 MB. If that much or little I do not know, but I am concerned when this structure holds 2-300k of rules. They are added via GUI - not by a programmer. The tree-structure is spread first alphabetically on the first letter on the rule (hash-map) then on a homegrown standard tree-implementation using ConcurrentSkipListSet for children (not sure why - we rebuild entire tree on creation).